# Rspec error, cannot load gem 'capybara' -- Inside Vagrant, Ruby 2.0 Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, vagrant

I'm currently upgrading the application's test frameworks, and have run into a knot here. I believe the issue is getting overcomplicated because I'm porting the app into Vagrant at the same time, but regardless, the issue is very curious.

Here is the stack trace when running `bundle exec rspec`

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'capybara'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/app/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/app/spec/controllers/administration/course_groups_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/app/spec/controllers/administration/course_groups_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `rescue in run'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `run'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@oaisd_uae_web_app/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Here are my capybara gem versions

```
capybara (2.5.0)
capybara-screenshot (0.3.3)
capybara-webkit (1.7.1)
```

Along with my rspec version of 2.99

In the stack trace, line 11 in application.rb is as follows:

```
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
```

And my relavent gemfile portions:

```
group :test do
  ...
  gem 'minitest',  '3.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber', '1.1.9'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'capybara', '2.5.0'
  gem "capybara-webkit", '1.7.1'
  gem "capybara-screenshot", '0.3.3'
  gem "nokogiri", '1.5.11'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.2'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '1.0.0'
  ...
end

group :development, :test do
  ...
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.99'
  gem 'jasmine', '1.3.2'
  gem 'teaspoon'
  gem 'teaspoon-jasmine'
  gem 'phantomjs'
  gem 'pry', '0.9.9.6'
  gem 'pry-rails', '0.1.6'
  gem 'pry-remote', '0.1.5'
  ...
end
```

And it *does* bundle! I also might add that my cucumber tests are running just fine. So capybara is working apart from rspec.

I've tried the following: Upgraded rspec to 3.0, upgraded ruby to 2.0, tried different versions of capybara, in case they aren't compatible. Does anyone have any suggestions for next steps?

Comment: What's in `spec_helper`?

Comment: Here's my `spec_helper.rb` https://gist.github.com/NickBeukema/83d5dbcd2527b573d2b9

Comment: For others with this issue, I totally missed a Capybara configuration in my lib directory (I know, poor placement). This caused a reference that running my rspec tests did not know how to handle, thus erroring the above.